# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' array using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a checkbox:

```
<input value="".$count_FRID."" name="rubric_chkbox[]" />
```

I'm using `jquery` and `ajax` to get the data and use `foreach` loop to insert it to my database as follows:

```
var rubricChkbox = new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    rubricChkbox['rubric_chkbox[]'].push($(this).val()); 
});
console.log(rubricChkbox);

$.ajax({
    url: "Queries/save.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "rubricChkbox":rubricChkbox
    },
    success: function(yey){
        console.log(yey);
        alert(yey);
    }
});
```

For deleting of checkbox:

```
<input value="1" name="rubric_chkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
<input value="2" name="rubric_chkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
```

jQuery and AJAX:

```
var rubricChkbox = new Array();
var uncheked = new Array();
$(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    rubricChkbox.push($(this).val()); 
});

$(".checkbox:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    uncheked.push($(this).val()); 
});
$.ajax({
    url: "Queries/save.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "rubricChkbox":rubricChkbox
    },
    success: function(yey){
    console.log(yey);
        alert(yey);
    }
});
```

For example if 1 and 2 values are inserted in my database, and if I unchecked checkbox 1 and 2, shouldn't the code above work for deleting rows?

I'm getting below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push'
```

EDIT, save.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['rubricChkbox']) || isset($_POST['uncheked']) || isset($_POST['user_id'])) {
    $rubric_value = $_POST['rubricChkbox'];
    $rubric_uncheck_value = $_POST['uncheked'];
    $IDuser = $_POST['user_id'];

    foreach($rubric_value as $rubric_check) {
        $sql_check = "SELECT raw_selected_rubric FROM rubric_selected INNER JOIN cmat_composition ON rubric_selected.ID_cmat = cmat_composition.ID_cmat WHERE rubric_selected.ID_users = '$IDuser' AND raw_selected_rubric = '$rubric_check' 
        AND rubric_selected.Saved = '1'";
        $result_check = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_check);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_check) <= 0){

            $sql_raw = "INSERT INTO rubric_selected (raw_selected_rubric, Saved, ID_users)

            VALUES  ('$rubric_check', '1', '$IDuser')";

            mysqli_query($conn, $sql_raw); 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put the brackets [ ] in your array variable. Use `rubricChkbox.push($(this).val());`

```
var rubricChkbox = new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function() {
       if($(this).attr("id") == "option1"){
          // if the id of checkbox is option1 then push it
          rubricChkbox.push($(this).val()); 
       }
});
console.log(rubricChkbox);

$.ajax({
    url: "Queries/save.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"rubricChkbox":rubricChkbox
    },
    success: function(yey){
      console.log(yey);
      alert(yey);
    }
});
```

Edit: For your additional question, yes you can add a class specific for your checkboxes and loop through them instead;

Run the code below.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var unchecked = new Array();

  $(".checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    unchecked.push($(this).val());
  });

  console.log(unchecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="rubric_chkbox[]" />
<input value="2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="rubric_chkbox[]" />
<button>Validate</button>
```

Comment: Can I have if/else condition inside in this $("input:checked").each(function() {
       (make this and if/else condition) rubricChkbox.push($(this).val()); 
}); sir?

Comment: @jeloneedshelp yes you can. Updated the answer. Added an if that would check the id of the checkbox

Comment: Would it work sir if I added class="checkBoxRubric" in my input field and get every checked checkboxes that has a class checkBoxRubric?

Comment: I'm sorry if I have a lot of questions sir. It's because I have another foreach loop that I uncheck that chekcbox it would delete that row in my database. I will edit my question for the delete query.

Comment: @jeloneedshelp please create a new question then comment it here so I would check, thanks

Comment: Oh wow that works sir however in my insert query if i checked 1 and 2 checkboxes only checkbox 1 is inserted. I'll show just you my save.php sir if maybe I missed out something.

Comment: Hi @jeloneedshelp please make a new question with your updated code. Thanks! Do comment here with the question link.

Comment: It's ok sir. Thank you so much for the help. :)

Comment: Sir I need your help again. Please?         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973007/delete-table-rows-using-jquery-and-ajax-foreach-loop

Comment: But I still need help from this problem of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943199/multiple-checkbox-values-inserting-using-foreach-loop-jquery-and-ajax/52943373#52943373    . Please help me sir. Thank you.