# delete table rows using jquery and ajax (foreach loop)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to delete table rows base on the uncheck checkbox of my input fields like this,

[image: input checkbox]

So these are input fields,

```
Level 1<input value="1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="rubric_chkbox[]" />
Level 2<input value="2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="rubric_chkbox[]" />
Level 3<input value="3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="rubric_chkbox[]" />
```

I'm using the next jquery code to get the data,

```
var uncheked = [];

$("input[name='rubric_chkbox[]']:not(:checked)").each(function()
{
    uncheked.push($(this).val()); 
});

console.log(uncheked);
```

Console.log return the array value ["3"] which is the unchecked checkbox value.

And this is my foreach loop on PHP,

```
if (isset($_POST['uncheked']) || isset($_POST['user_id']))
{
    $rubric_uncheck_value = $_POST['uncheked'];    
    $IDuser = $_POST['user_id'];

    foreach($rubric_uncheck_value as $rubric_uncheck)
    {
        $sql_check = "SELECT raw_selected_rubric
                      FROM rubric_selected
                      INNER JOIN cmat_composition ON rubric_selected.ID_cmat = cmat_composition.ID_cmat
                      WHERE rubric_selected.ID_users = '$IDuser'
                      AND raw_selected_rubric = '$rubric_uncheck'
                      AND rubric_selected.Saved = '1'";

        $result_check = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_check);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_check) > 0)
        {                
            $sql_raw = "DELETE raw_selected_rubric
                        FROM rubric_selected
                        WHERE raw_selected_rubric = '$rubric_uncheck'
                        AND ID_users = ''$IDuser'";

            mysqli_query($conn, $sql_raw);

            $sql_to_validated = "DELETE selected_rubric
                                 FROM validated_score
                                 WHERE selected_rubric = '$rubric_uncheck'
                                 AND ID_users = ''$IDuser'";

            mysqli_query($conn, $sql_to_validated);
        }
    }
}
```

But this does nothing. What can be the problem? Help please. Thank you.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? This post needs more details before it can be answered. Can you confirm that the unchecked and userid are correctly being passed to your server?

Comment: I'm expecting that the return value 3 would be deleted from my database

Comment: And yes sir the unchecked and userid are correctly being passed.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry I'm such and idiot. I've solved it. My problem is that in my delete query above, I should first select the table that I want to delete some data like this, "DELETE FROM rubric_selected WHERE raw_selected_rubric = '$rubric_uncheck'
                AND ID_cmat = '$ID_cmat' AND ID_users = '$IDuser'";

Comment: Anyways thank you for the help Mr. @colefner. :)

Comment: Don't worry, I've had 1000s of those moments. Next time, chat with your rubber duck about it :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Haha thanks again Mr.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.